# How Can we monitor MYSQL DB table in realtime for any update and insert using PHP(Without cron) or any other scripting language?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, api, lumen

How Can we monitor MYSQL DB table in realtime for any update and insert using PHP(Without cron) or any other scripting language?

I have a work flow as.

A PHP API call(Lumen) will add a new entry to a table.
The system will continuously check that row for X sec(using cron).
The X seconds checking is for any updates done over this row using a cancel API.
The mobile app user can cancel this request with in X seconds.

I have tried to implement this with PHP cron-job running on every seconds.
But we assume that it wont be the good solution.

Is there any other tools that we can use instead of Cron for this ?

Our initial logic is to hold the API for 15 sec and the return the result like

```
$this->timer = new LaravelTimer();
$this->timer->timerStart(id);
$time = $this->timer->timerRead(id); 

    while(floor($time) < 16000) 
        {
    
            if(//Checking for cancel Request Here)
                 
                //Break the loop  if cancel request came from second API
                //Return API Response
            } else
            {                                                           
                $time = $this->timer->timerRead(id); 
                if (floor($time) >= 15000) {
                 //Break the loop  and return API Response
                }
    
                //Continue Loop
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the meaning of your 'realtime monitoring'. I imagine that you wanna inform the data changes to frontend apps. Few of many solutions are:

1. Add monitoring script (such as callback script function after your INSERT/UPDATE script). For example if you use websocket connection to inform the frontend app in browser using javascript or write a report to text file sequentially:

```
//1. your INSERT/UPDATE script
//2. do your reporting/monitoring callback script here as like sending to websocket server or writing data changes report to a file
```

2. Instead of cron, and if you use a PHP-framework like laravel, just use laravel queue to run you script as background job periodically. Just take the theory of this doc: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues
3. If you really want to use while-loop to check the data changes and inform to frontend, you can use Server-Sent Events method in PHP.

Hope these options help you.

Comment: By the word  'realtime monitoring' -  i want to check continuously for 15 seconds in a DB column for the cancel request update(Second API Call). After 15 seconds i have to call a third party API and exit the code execution. I have to apply this checking for each user logins. Sorry for the confusion.. API is used by the mobile APP.

Comment: I think better way is using cron or mini cron-like method such as 'supervisor', the main difference between using endless-loop method and cron-like method is in memory usage. Cron-like method will always release/reset memory usage periodically in every it's job.